# Regular expressions not being found

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I have the following function that's supposed to check a text file for dates using regular expressions and then I have the slot from my gui class below the check function that's supposed to append all dates found by the check function to a QTextEdit.  For some reason nothing gets appended to the QTextEdit even though I am running the check function on a text file that contains a few dates.  Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

code:

```
QStringList RegExChecker::check(QStringList textToCheck) {
    QRegExp dayInText("\\d{1, 2]\\W");
    QRegExp monthInText("\\d{1, 2}|\\.\\.\\.*\\W");
    QRegExp yearInText("19\\d\\d|20\\d\\d");

    QStringList datesFound;

    for (int i = 1; i <= textToCheck.size(); ++i) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= textToCheck.size(); ++j) {
             for (int k = j + 1; k <= textToCheck.size(); ++k) {
                if ((dayInText.exactMatch(textToCheck.at(i)) || yearInText.exactMatch(textToCheck.at(i)))
                        && monthInText.exactMatch(textToCheck.at(j))
                        && (yearInText.exactMatch(textToCheck.at(k)) || dayInText.exactMatch(textToCheck.at(k)))) {
                    datesFound.append(QString("%1 %2 %3").arg(textToCheck.at(i)).arg(textToCheck.at(j)).arg(textToCheck.at(k)));
                }
             }
         }
     }
     return datesFound;

}

void MainWindow::checkText() {
    RegExChecker rc;
    QStringList dates = rc.check(text);
    foreach (QString str, dates)
        ui->txtContents->append(str);
}
```

Comment: What text do you pass? BTW, you have a typo at `QRegExp dayInText("\\d{1, 2]\\W");` (there must be `\\d{1,2}`). Also, remove the space in `\\d{1, 2}`.

Comment: You should reformat the code in your question so we can read it without a lot of horizontal scrolling.  That turned me right off, and I'm sure it's doing the same to others.

Comment: @Alan Moore sorry for the difficulty in reading.  I'm blind and using a screen reader so I don't know where the horizontal scrolling is needed.  If you can give me an exact line i'll change it right away...

Comment: @user2094257  Thanks for taking a look.  The text i'm passing is a file containing 2 lines of text where each line contains a date.

Comment: Best is to give examples where you think the regex should match but it doesn't

Comment: The text i'm passing to the check function is:  Name:  a  Date formed:  2015-08-16  Employees:  2
Name:  v  Date formed:  2015-08-16  Charitable status Charitable

Comment: I went ahead and reformatted the code myself.

Comment: Thanks @Alan Moore much appreciated:)